# How to create column by get everything after and before some characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have table in SQL Server like below:

```
select col from table

col1
------
02-567 City, ul. ABc 44, woj. Zak
56-123 City2, ul. Grt 78, woj. Maaap
44-153 Raw, Pl. 777, woj. Rapat
```

And I need to create query which will give me result like below:

```
col1                                  col2   col3
----------------------------------------------------
02-567 City, ul. ABc 44, woj. Zak     City   ul. ABc 44
56-123 City2, ul. Grt 78, woj. Maaap  City2  ul. Grt 78
44-153 Raw, Pl. 777, woj. Rapat       Raw    Pl. 777
```

So:

- 1. To create col2 I need to take everything after first space till first coma
- 2. To create col3 I need to take everything which start after space after first coma till second coma

How can I do than in SQL Server?

Comment: what have you tried so far? you already tagged `charindex` and `substr` there

Comment: I wrote charindex and substring because I assume that it should be used here but I do not know how

Comment: RoMe... do you know how to solve my problem? I try to research internet but it is not easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select col1
, col2 = right(left(col1,charindex(',',col1)-1),charindex(',',col1)-1-charindex(' ',col1))
, col3 = ltrim(replace(reverse(parsename(replace(replace(reverse(col1),'.','•'),',','.'),2)),'•','.'))
from [table]
```

Ugly, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little less ugly :), but I suspect a nudge less performant than LukStorms' answer.

**Example**

```
Select  Col1
       ,Col2 =  stuff(Pos1,1,charindex(' ',Pos1+' '),'')
       ,Col3 =  Pos2
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select  Pos1 =  trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'))
                      ,Pos2 =  trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'))
                From  (values ( '["'+replace(string_escape([Col1],'json'),',','","')+'"]' ) ) B1(S) 
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
Col1                                   Col2     Col3
02-567 City, ul. ABc 44, woj. Zak      City     ul. ABc 44
56-123 City2, ul. Grt 78, woj. Maaap   City2    ul. Grt 78
44-153 Raw, Pl. 777, woj. Rapat        Raw      Pl. 777
```

Comment: Only a little less ugly. ;)  *(why can't MS just include the regexp functions for foo's sake)*  But it's a method that will be more useful for extracting more than 2.